# moderncv, casual style, how to put the contact information in the header

Tags: header-footer, moderncv

I'm using the `moderncv` package with the casual style to write a letter. There the personal data are written at the bottom of the page. Is there a way to put them into the header?

Here is a is MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1,ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 


\firstname{Max}
\familyname{Mustermann}
\address{Musterstraße}{Musterstadt}    
\mobile{ABCDEF}                      
\email{ABCDEF}


\opening{Dear Sir or Madam, } 
\closing{Yours Sincerely, }

\recipient{Erika Mustermann}{Musterstadt}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\date{Musterstadt, den \today}
\makelettertitle
Text
\makeletterclosing
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can patch the `\makeletterfooter` macro to place the contents of the footer in the header. Since [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) uses [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) it's as simple as replacing `\fancyfoot` with `\fancyhead` (and some header height adjustment):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\makeletterfooter}{\fancyfoot}{\fancyhead}{}{}
\setlength{\headheight}{36pt}
```

Here is a complete minimal example showing the output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\makeletterfooter}{\fancyfoot}{\fancyhead}{}{}
\setlength{\headheight}{36pt}


\firstname{Max}
\familyname{Mustermann}
\address{Musterstraße}{Musterstadt}
\mobile{ABCDEF}
\email{ABCDEF}


\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours Sincerely,}

\recipient{Erika Mustermann}{Musterstadt}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\date{Musterstadt, den \today}
\makelettertitle
Text
\makeletterclosing
\end{document}
```